# What is the difference between "DOMContent Event" and DOMContentLoaded in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

In the developer tools there is a blue line called "DOMContent Event" is this the same as "DOMContentLoaded" in the JavaScript events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out "DOMContent Event" is from webkit (which chrome relies on) and is equivelant to DOMContentLoaded.

**EDIT**: As of now (July 2012, Chrome 20) Chrome is supporting "DOMContentLoaded" as well, so you can use this and be sure, that it will be correctly supported in both Chrome, FF, as good as Safari and other WebKit-based browsers (still not supported in IE, AFAIK).